# How can I catch django.http.request.DisallowedHost in a view?

Tags: python, django

This works:

```
def index(request):

    try:
        # Do some stuff

    except:
        return render(request, 'something.html')
```

But how can I catch just the error: `django.http.request.DisallowedHost` ?

Have tried this and it doesn't work:

```
from django.core.exceptions import DisallowedHost

def index(request):

    try:
        # Do some stuff

    except DisallowedHost:
        return render(request, 'something.html')
```

Comment: Why would you want to catch this? You know if you add '*' in your allowd_hosts in settings you will not have this exception?

Comment: @AmirAfianian My project serves many domains.  When someone points there servers at us but does not update the domain in the application I want to display a helpful error message rather than just a 500.

Comment: Is `django.http.request.DisallowedHost` the same as `django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost`?

Answer (score 5):

Please don't replace middleware or do some other weird stuff. It's very simple: DisallowedHost() is raised by the first thing that calls `get_host()` on a request object. Typically, this is a middleware, because doing it too early in the request/response cycle would make it impossible to turn off or customize.

So inject your custom middleware first in the chain and shortcircuit things there:

```py
# File: main.middleware
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.exceptions import DisallowedHost


class FriendlyDisallowedHost:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            checkhost = request.get_host()
        except DisallowedHost:
            return redirect("http://localhost/")
        
        return self.get_response(request)
```

settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "main.middleware.FriendlyDisallowedHost",
    # ... rest of middleware
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom middleware for this.

For that, create a custom middleware by sub-classing the [**`CommonMiddleware`**--(Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware) class and override the [**`process_request(...)`**--(Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) method

```
# some_place/some_module.py

from django.middleware.common import CommonMiddleware
from django.core.exceptions import DisallowedHost
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


class CustomCommonMiddleware(CommonMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            return super().process_request(request)
        except DisallowedHost:
            return render(request, 'something.html')
```

Then, replace the **`django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware`** middleware with the newly created custom class in [**`MIDDLEWARE`**-(Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE) settings as,

```
# settings.py

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # other middleware
    'some_place.some_module.CustomCommonMiddleware', # add this
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', # Remove this
    # other middleware
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Django will intercept the request and raise this exception before it even calls your view, you should use a [custom error view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) for handling these kinds of errors overriding the [default error views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/views/)

In your application view, write the handler you want for handling `DisallowedHost`

```py
from django.views.defaults import bad_request as default_bad_request
from django.core.exceptions import DisallowedHost
from django.http import HttpResponse


def my_bad_request_handler(request, exception=None, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(exception, DisallowedHost):
        return HttpResponse("This server is not configured for this hostname", status=400)
    # if it's some other kind of bad request, use Django's default handler
    return default_bad_request(request, exception, **kwargs)
```

Then in your URLConf set the 400 handler to your custom view:

```py
handler400 = 'mysite.views.my_bad_request_handler'
```

See also: [SuspiciousOperation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/exceptions/#suspiciousoperation) exception and [400 bad request view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/views/#the-400-bad-request-view).